# where can I find a complete list of the Haskell modules?

Tags: haskell

I found that http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ has a big list and references but GHCI has a different list (i.e. when you are trying to load a module, GHCI gives you a list of the submodules, that is different, in number, than the one on the web)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list you linked to is a selection of widespread packages (which one is shown on the right). What e.g. GHCi offers you is the selection of packages installed *on your system* with `ghc-pkg`; installing such packages is usually done with `cabal install <package name>`. So if you'd like to use some module but ghci won't let you, try installing the package first. If you want to browse the documentation for a module you have installed, but can't find it in the hierarchical libraries list, just [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) the package name (if you don't know which one it is: `ghc-pkg find-module <module-name>` tells you) and you'll get a link to its Haddock documentation.

If you just want a list of all easily available modules, that's a lot. [Here's the list of all packages on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html), i.e. all you can simply install with `cabal install`.

Answer (score 3):

Things will vary depending on what platform you are on, and how you installed ghc; this was probably announced to you sometime during installation in one of those forgettable moments. But with something like unix `locate` or some other file-system search, you can find the User's guide and the documentation for the libraries that came with ghc by doing something like

```
 locate docs/index.html
```

This page will link a *Libraries* page like the one you linked.  If you have a local `~$HOME/.cabal` directory the docs for the libraries you have installed with `cabal install` are listed in

```
 $HOME/.cabal/share/doc/index.html
```

or the like.  If `cabal install` is putting things somewhere else, it can again be found with something like

```
 locate doc/index.html
```

So then just open them in a browser and bookmark the links. The latter page is updated by `haddock` whenever you install something with `cabal install`

Comment: IIRC you have to set `documentation: True` in `~/.cabal/config` if you want this.

Comment: Ah I think that's right, it's not the default -- but if not, by all means do that, though compiling will take a little longer since it will put haddock to work. In some arrangements, e.g. I think the new OS X haskell platform and maybe the still-current one, the `config` file will be somewhere else, something to do with `Libraries` and `Frameworks`.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian, the documentation of all packages installed via `apt-get` ist available at

```
file:///usr/share/doc/ghc-doc/html/libraries/index.html
```

(at least if you have installed the `-doc` packages for all your `-dev` packages.)

Answer (score 2):

The "*latest*" in the URL may give you a view different than what it is available in your ghc version.

So check your version and substitute it in the URL as in

GHC libraries: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/

Haskell platform libraries: http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/2012.4.0.0/ (subst. the last part with your version nr.)

The platform and compiler libraries may be overriden by installed updated packages, so

- `ghc-pkg list` will list your package versions.
- then look for the proper documentation in hackage (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/  *package-name*)

for GHCi, it has access to the same libraries as the compiler, plus the packages you give at start with the -package flag.